Generating data for Gumbel's bivariate exponential distribution in python
For a bivariate random vector $(X,Y)$ with survival function $\bar{F}(x,y)=\mathrm{e}^{-ax-by-\theta xy}$, $\theta\in(0,1)$. I want to generate random data in python. Also I want to see mathematical approach. Please help me out. Thanks beforehand!

Consider the use of a marginal density (exponential distributed) and a conditional density (mixture of exponential and gamma distribution), which are easy to sample from. These marginal and conditional densities are described in E. J. Gumbel Journal of the American Statistical Association
Vol. 55, No. 292 (Dec., 1960), pp. 698-707.
